# Is \textquotedblleft and \textquotedblright required for quotation marks?

Tags: quoting

Can I just use `"sometext"` or do I have to use the commands for a quotation mark?  If I don't, why would I ever use them?  The interpreter I am using ([Scientific Word](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/sw.html~mainFrame)) and it interprets it as regular quote marks, but I have other LaTeX that already exists with the commands `\textquotedblleft` and  `\textquotedblright`.  Do I need the commands or can I use `""`?

Edit:

I looked a little closer and it looks like `"` is not the same as what the LaTeX command gives.

Comment: You should not use ". I always use the csquotes package and \enquote{my quoted text}.

Comment: never use `"` the traditional markup is `\`\`word''`  (two back ticks and two single quotes) but the csquotes package is more flexible.